# Execute PHP code on form submit without text input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just want to know if it is possible to execute a PHP post request with ajax by click on a form submit button that does not have any text input. Say i have a form

```
<form action="connecting.php" id="connect" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="submit" name="userconnect" id="userconnect" value="connect">
</form>
```

And i want to execute this block of php code on submit button

**connecting.php**

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['userconnect']))
    {
        $my_id = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['log_id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $user_id = (int) htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['userid'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $rand_num = rand();

        $hsql =<<<EOF
    SELECT COUNT(hash) as count FROM connect WHERE (user_one = '$my_id' AND user_two = '$user_id') OR (user_two = '$my_id' AND user_one = '$user_id');
EOF;

        $hret = $db->querySingle($hsql);

        if ($hret == 1)
        {
            echo "<script>alert('You are already connected to this user')</script>";
        }
        else
        {

            $usql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO connect (user_one, user_two, hash) VALUES (:my_id, :user_id, :rand_num)");
            $usql->bindValue(':my_id', $my_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            $usql->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
            $usql->bindValue(':rand_num', $rand_num, SQLITE3_TEXT);

            $uret = $usql->execute();

            if (!$uret)
            {
                echo "Error connecting";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Connection Sucessful";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the ajax request i am trying to use

```
$("#connect").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "connecting.php",
    data: $(this).serializeArray(), //the data is an issue cause of no text input in for 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
    }
});
});
```

This doesn't work because there is no data in the form for ajax to send but all data are in the PHP file. How do i execute the php file with ajax. Is there any way?

Comment: Simply remove - data: $(this).serializeArray(). serializeArray()  encodes a set of form elements as an array of names and values and there are no form elements in this form.

Comment: Hold on: is this just about running a script on the server after the user clicks a button...? You don't need a `<form>` at all in this case.

Comment: Yea sure but i figured if i prevent default action it doesn't matter. Right ?@ChrisG

Comment: @diagold Right, but all you need is `$("#connect").click(function () { $.get("connecting.php"); });`

Comment: @ChrisG tried without the form and used a div instead but it doesn't insert to database. But all works without ajax (with the form)

Comment: You need to adjust your `connecting.php` accordingly. You aren't sending along any parameters, so you need to remove the outer check for `isset($_POST['userconnect'])`

Comment: Oh yea. Thats it definitely. That should owrk. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to send a POST request to a PHP script in order for it to execute. You can send a normal GET to a URL that executes a PHP script and send you back the JSON data you are looking for. That way, you dont have to send data with the post request and you can still run your PHP script.

Edit*
Another thing you can do is add a hidden ID field or some random text and send that with the POST as data. You dont have to do anything with it, it could just be a time stamp, but it will send the POST request. This is of course overhead and not my kind of programming, but an option nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.... you need to harness a click event...

for example if you had a div element like so:
`<div id='mybutton'>click me</div>`

then you could use code like this to do literally whatever you want when the button is clicked.:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click',function(){
   $.post...
});
```

BONUS INFO:
You could also hijack the form submit event like so:

```
 $('#form#myform').on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault(); //stop before page is reloaded with post headers
       $.post...
    });
```

You don't actually need a form event though, you can just $.get to a php url and return the html or json it generates. just check out the jquery documentation on $.get()